Find a function $u$ that solves this boundary value problem (using the weak formulation).
This exercise is paraphrased from page 8 of Finite Elements: An Introduction Volume 1 (Becker, Cary, Oden):

The identity function is defined by $\mathbf I (x) = x$. Concatenating functions will be the Hadamard product (matching, element-wise multiplication of image points), rather than composition.
$H$ is the space of all functions of form $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that are smooth, square integrable, and vanish on the endpoints. Have $u, v \in H$. Solve for $u$ such that$$-u'' = \mathbf I $$
and the weak formulation
$$ \int \limits_0^1 (-u'v' - \mathbf I v) \,dx = 0 \;\;\;\; \text{for all } v \in H$$
is satisfied.

Answer: Function $u$ vanishes at the endpoints, so we have by a trivial application of product rule that $$\int \limits_0^1 u' v' \, dx = \int \limits_0^1 -u'' v \, dx$$ Accordingly, the weak formulation can be rewritten as $$ \int \limits_0^1 (-u'' - \mathbf I) v \,dx = 0$$ which from this previous answer gives $$u = {\mathbf I - \mathbf I^3\over 6} $$

Did shifting the weak formulation into a problem with a pre-existing solution work and give the correct answer?

What exactly is the difficulty you are facing? the function $u(x) = (x-x^3)/6$ satisfies the differential equation and the boundary condition. So yes, your solution is correct.
